# Querying combination of two keys in a single JSON column in table in Postgres database

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm working with a database (running Postgres 13) table which has a JSON column which has a structure that looks roughly like this:

```
{
  first_name: 'Alex',
  last_name: 'Smith',
  my_other: 'info',
  ...
}
```

I need to write a query that searches by the full name of the user (i.e., `"#{first_name} #{last_name}"`), but I can't figure out how to build a "virtualized" full name column that combines the values in the first and last name keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test if the JSON column contains both the first and lastname, you can do:

```
where the_column @> '{"first_name": "Alex", "last_name": "Smith"}'::jsonb
```

This assumes that your JSON columns is of type `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it: `the_column::jsonb`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to concatenate the two values using the `||` operator. If the json column is named `col` and the table `A` then you can do:

```
SELECT (col->>'first_name') || ' ' || (col->>'last_name') FROM A
```

The `->>` operator extracts a field from a json object as `text`, i.e., exactly what you want. (I used some parentheses because right now I don't remeber the precedence between `||` and `->>`)

Also, note that yuo don't need a "virtualized" full name if you want to just check if the json column contains two properties. You can just use the `@>` (or `<@`) operator.